# NSArray sortUsingFunction custom object always at the end

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

Please help. I have NSArray with custom objects in it. For example Person, so the Person with name 'Mark' should be always at the end. Is it possible to do it with help of 'sortUsingFunction'?
I guess something like that, here is sort function:

```
static NSInteger compareFunction(id item1, id item2, void *context)
{
   Person *pItem1 = (Person *)item1;
   Person *pItem2 = (Person *)item2;

   if ([pItem1.name isEqual:@"Mark"])
   {
      return NSOrderedDescending;
   }
}
```

Note: it should be sortUsingFunction, no other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your idea is feasible. Here is a tested example:

```
NSArray *names = @[@"John",@"Mark",@"Sandy"];
NSArray *markEndArray = [names sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *_Nonnull obj1, NSString *_Nonnull obj2) {
    if ([obj1 isEqualToString:@"Mark"]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];

NSLog(@"%@",markEndArray);

//Output:    
    John,
    Sandy,
    Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

Yun CHEN's version does not work completely. Trying with the following names it fails:

```
NSArray *names = @[
    @"John",
    @"Noah",
    @"Liam",
    @"Mason",
    @"Jacob",
    @"William",
    @"Ethan",
    @"James",
    @"Alexander",
    @"Michael",
    @"Mark",
    @"Benjamin",
    @"Elijah",
    @"Daniel",
    @"Aiden",
    @"Logan",
    @"Matthew",
    @"Lucas",
    @"Jackson",
    @"David",
    @"Oliver",
    @"Jayden",
    @"Sandy"
];
```

Wrong result:

```
Aiden,
Alexander,
Benjamin,
Daniel,
David,
Elijah,
Ethan,
Jackson,
Jacob,
James,
Jayden,
John,
Liam,
Logan,
Lucas,
Matthew,
Oliver,
Sandy,
Mark,
Mason,
Michael,
Noah,
William
```

You have to extend it like this:

```
NSArray *markEndArray = [names sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *_Nonnull obj1, NSString *_Nonnull obj2) {
    if ([obj1 isEqualToString:@"Mark"]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if ([obj2 isEqualToString:@"Mark"]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        return [obj1 compare:obj2];
    }
}];
```

Then it should be perfectly fine!